# How to determine between a Baker's Cyst and a Deep-Vein-Thrombosis (DVT) behind knee?

Tags: knee, blood-clotting, bruising-bruise

Are there side by side image compairsons of what a Baker's Cysts (behind a knee) and a Deep Vein thrombosis (DVT) blood clot behind the knee looks like?

I know Baker's Cysts, while painful, are not life-threatening whereas as a DVT blood-clot is, and I'm having a hard time knowing what a deep purple and red spotted bruise behind the knee is serious or just the knocks around of life. (Not asking for a diagnosis). Just wondering if there is a side by side comparison of the commonalities and differentces of Baker's Cysts and DVT.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Baker's cyst** typically appears as a single or multiple lump with clearly defined borders, covered by normal skin without discoloration ([Google photos of Baker's cysts](https://www.google.com/search?q=baker%20cyst&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=itp:photo&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQsaTX1-TRAhVEuBQKHWA2Cv8QpwUIEg&biw=1366&bih=638&dpr=1&gws_rd=cr&ei=V3qMWPDZH4KMUb-XkbgF)).

**Varicose veins** behind the knee appear as a net of knotted bluish threads ([Photo](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fedenlifenigeria.com%2Feden_imagesblog%2Fvaricose-veins-for-you-mini-skirt-lovers-3.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fedenlifenigeria.com%2Fvaricose-veins-for-you-mini-skirt-lovers%2F&docid=ATd_PMyYOLKLIM&tbnid=c-V4VrGhWLrjqM%3A&vet=1&w=450&h=300&bih=638&biw=1366&q=varicose%20veins%20knee&ved=0ahUKEwivq-Tl_uTRAhUEWywKHRqqCwgQMwghKAYwBg&iact=mrc&uact=8)).

**Superficial thrombophlebitis** can appear as a vague red discoloration without swelling on the lower leg rather than behind the knee ([2 photos](http://www.dermnetnz.org/topics/superficial-thrombophlebitis/)).

**Deep vein thrombosis** typically appears as a bluish patchy discoloration (not net-like like in varicose veins) and swelling in the lower leg (not likely behind the knee) [(scroll to the image 4)](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1911303-overview?pa=3FYVxc59RqYkf4YmhFhFpOq83ROJLgbwhTa4GgH8ETATZkSHcqE1Jwouv2p8isxcNFsYxDuz%2Fz2hge3aAwEFsw%3D%3D). Google search for "deep vein thrombosis behind knee" gives [this misleading result](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1366&bih=638&tbs=itp%3Aphoto&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=deep%20vein%20thrombosis%20behind%20knee&oq=deep%20vein%20thrombosis%20behind%20knee&gs_l=img.3..0j0i30k1j0i24k1l2.46376.52995.0.53233.32.32.0.0.0.0.147.2716.26j6.32.0.foo%2Ccfro%3D1%2Cnso-enfk%3D1%2Cnso-usnt%3D1%2Cnso-qnt-npqp%3D0-21%2Cnso-qnt-npdq%3D0-57%2Cnso-qnt-npt%3D0-16%2Cnso-qnt-ndc%3D800%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mnp%3D0-085%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mxp%3D0-2125%2Cnso-unt-npqp%3D0-21%2Cnso-unt-npdq%3D0-35%2Cnso-unt-npt%3D0-1%2Cnso-unt-ndc%3D400%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mnp%3D0-0125%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mxp%3D0-0875...0...1.1.64.img..0.32.2695...0i67k1j0i8i30k1.qpsXS2WuiFY), because most of those photos actually show varicose veins.